# Как упростить проникновение зависимостей в коде?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-search-view

Есть android приложение. Суть простая - 1 `Activity`, 2 `Fragment`, `ActionBar` с `SearchView` и еще одной кнопкой (для вызова 2 фрагмента).

Суть в том что когда отображаются результаты поиска пользователь может нажать на один из вариантов, предлагаемым под `SearchView`, что за собой повлечет обновление (по факту пересоздание) 1 `Fragment` c уже новыми данными.

Проблема в том, как мне показалось, что данный механизм цепочки не очень корректный и достаточно сложный, как его можно упростить?

Вкратце. `ViewHolder` реализует `OnClickListener` который использует `CursorAdapter` (который использует `SearchView`) имеет ссылку на `MainActivity`, который при клике на ту или иную позицию вызывает метод в `MainActivity` на переприсоединение фрагмента с уже новыми данными.

Сам код (несущественные моменты упустил)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
private SearchView mSearchView;
private GeneralSearchListener listener;
private SQLAdapter mSQLAdapter;
private Cursor mCursor;
private CityNameCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    changeFragment(GeneralFragment.newInstance("Moscow")).commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    mSQLAdapter = new SQLAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    mCursor = mSQLAdapter.getCityNamesList();
    //первая на мой взгляд сложная инициализация объекта с громоздким конструктором
    mCursorAdapter = new CityNameCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mCursor, 0, this); 
    //вторая еще более сложная, но без MainActivity
    listener = new GeneralSearchListener(getApplicationContext(),
                                            mCursor,
                                            mSQLAdapter,
                                            mCursorAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener);
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    //todo go next step...
    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void loadNewCity(String cityName) {
    //...create new fragment and set
}}
```

И Сам адаптер:

```
public class CityNameCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private static BaseActivity mMainActivity;

    //Большой некрасивый конструктор
    public CityNameCursorAdapter(Context context, final Cursor c, final int flags, BaseActivity mainActivity) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mMainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_search_view, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        holder.mTextViewCityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_search_view_item);
        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        //...lot of code

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.mTextViewCityName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CityName.KEY_name)));
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView mTextViewCityName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //и все ради того что бы отловить клик по определенному элементу с определенным именем
            mMainActivity.loadNewCity(mTextViewCityName.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Есть мысль добавить в `xml` файле отвечающий за отображение элемента, но на сколько я знаю то совсем плохая практика